# How to wrap the items in a <xe:djextListTextBox> at a certain width

Tags: lotus-domino, xpages

I am trying to wrap the items in a `xe:djextListTextBox` so that when I have added items to a specific width the next item added starts at a new line.

Currently I have the `xe:djextListTextBox` in a table cell and my items are extending the cell instead of wrapping.

I have tried plenty of stuff but can't seem to figure it out.

This is one tecnique I used in my stylesheet:

```
SPAN[id$='djextListTextBox10']{width:200px}
```

Thanks for your help

Image show the items are extending the table width, if I add an item containg a space the items seem to wrap ok

[image: Image show the items are extending the table width, if I add an item containg a space the items seem to wrap ok]

```
<xp:panel style="width:300px">
<xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox10"
    multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true"
    value="#{userdocbasic.fld}" displayLabel="true"
    style="font-weight:bold;width:300px" type="text" tooltip="Select"
    title="nnn">
</xe:djextListTextBox>
</xp:panel>




<div style="width:300px">
<span id="widget_view:_id1:dynC:_id96:djextListTextBox10" wairole="presentation"     style="font-weight: bold; width: 300px; " class=""    dojoattachevent="onmouseenter:_onMouse,onmouseleave:_onMouse,onmousedown:_onMouse" role="presentation" widgetid="view:_id1:dynC:_id96:djextListTextBox10">
<input name="view:_id1:dynC:_id96:djextListTextBox10" dojoattachpoint="textbox" type="hidden" dojoattachevent="onchange: _onTextChange" value="item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11,item12">
<span dojoattachpoint="list,focusNode" class="lotusFilters lotusInlineList" id="view:_id1:dynC:_id96:djextListTextBox10" tabindex="-1" title="User defined skills">
<span val="item1" style="" tabindex="0"><a href="javascript:;" tabindex="-1"  class="lotusFilter">item1<span class="lotusClose">x</span></a></span></span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thomas, can you the XSP for the controls, etc - its hard to work out the style without seeing what the code is.  Thanks - jeremy

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I will answer my own question here...

as I was looking more deeply into the code I saw that there is a hidden input field  displaying each item like this: 
item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,item6,item7,item8,item9,item10,item11,item12

so I did a bit of reasearch and I seem to need css word-wrap: break-word
SPAN[id$='djextListTextBox10']{width:200px;word-wrap: break-word}

Answer (score 2):

setting 'word-wrap: break-word;' can cause word breaks in the middle of words. So I use a 'DIV' around the field with `class="someName"` and in CSS I have `.someName span span { float: left; }`